Git-LFS not tracking files properly: yolov8x.pt
It's my first time making a Git repository and I'm creating an object-detection model for a portfolio project.
I'm trying to make my first commit and I'm running into a problem because my yolov8x.pt file is larger than the 100.00 MB limit on GitHub's file size so it directed me to use Git LFS. After setting up LFS following all instructions and set the tracking on '*.pt' and 'yolov8x.pt' I still am receiving the same error.
Here is what the error looks like in my VS terminal:
remote: error: Trace: 9317b416ba008163a1102dee9c9b93b3bc82eeb5ba348b7fbf4bf4662ce76e5a
remote: error: See https://gh.io/lfs for more information.
remote: error: File yolov8x.pt is 130.53 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage
I assumed that tracking and then properly seeing the files tracked in gitattributes would mean that pushing the commit would work, but I still have not been able to properly commit all files to my repository.
Here is my .gitattributes file:
*.pt filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
yolov8x.pt filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
